# Is the events option in MaterializeCSS supposed to highlight dates?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, materialize

According to the [docs](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html), the `events` option is

> An array of string returned by `Date.toDateString()`, indicating there
> are events in the specified days.

Seems to me, this is supposed to highlight dates in the picker but it doesn't.

For example, is the code below supposed to highlight `2023-01-02` and `2023-01-05`?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  M.Datepicker.init(document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker'), {

    events: [
      new Date('2023-01-02').toDateString(),
      new Date('2023-01-05').toDateString()
    ],

    showClearBtn: true

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

test date:
<br>
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

How do you properly highlight dates?

Answer (score 1):

It adds just the class "has-event" to the selected days. You have to style it in CSS.